# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space using Matlab R2013a

Tags: java, matlab

I am  new for mat-lab and java , so i would like to list add in while loop .below i have mentioned ?

OS: Windows 7 ,64 bit .

- **On Mat-lab Part Side**

---

```
list=java.util.ArrayList();
for k=1:length(matrix)
list.add(int32(matrix(k)));
end
import edu.lipreading.*;
training = MainMethod;
training.list_method(list);
```

---

1. **on Java Class Part Side**

   ```
   public void list_method(List<Integer> points){

      while(true){

        Sample sample = new Sample();

        sample.getMatrix().add(points);}

    }
   ```

**When I am run my mat-lab i got  Error :**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
    at java.util.Vector.ensureCapacityHelper(Vector.java:226)
    at java.util.Vector.add(Vector.java:728)
    at edu.lipreading.MainMethod.onRecord(MainMethod.java:40)
    at edu.lipreading.MainMethod.list_method(MainMethod.java:26)
```

Note : I have referred link also : [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066495/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-on-startup)

Comment: Why is the while loop infinite?

Comment: thanks for reply me . because i am list add i expected result like  sample.getMatrix().add(points); //My List values are like   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8][9,8,3,2,2,43,22,1] [33,2,2,2,23,2,2,2] etc

Answer (score 1):

If you're running out of Java heap space in MATLAB, you can increase the amount of memory assigned to it in the MATLAB preferences.

Depending on your version of MATLAB, open the preferences dialog either by selecting Preferences from the File menu, or clicking Preferences in the toolstrip.

Under the section General, Java Heap Memory, you should find a setting that controls the Java heap size. The default is pretty low, so increase it to whatever you feel is necessary. You'll need to restart MATLAB to have that setting take effect.

Comment: Thanks for reply me .i have increased java heap size  maximum up to  1433 MB set after i have closed my mat-lab then again  i have run my mat-lab application  again i got same error ?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need infinite while loop, for your case this will work assuming getMatrix returns a list object and you are adding another list to it.

```
     Sample sample = new Sample();

     sample.getMatrix().add(points);
```

if you want to add only the contents of list to getMatrix() list then you can do:

```
     sample.getMatrix().addAll(points);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply me , i have tried Collection public void list_method(Collection<? extends List<Integer>> points){sample.getMatrix().addAll(points);} I have got result output like :Sample [id=web cam 10:41:06 11/03/2014, matrix=[136, 41, 1, 41, 77, 8, 77, 72]] ;Sample [id=web cam 10:41:12 11/03/2014, matrix=[170, 49, 10, 49, 88, 10, 88, 84]] etc..I have expected to get result like Sample [id=web cam 10:41:12 11/03/2014, matrix=[136,41,1,41,77,8,77,72],[170, 49, 10, 49, 88, 10, 88, 84]]

Comment: Can you please show your calling code and Sample Class code

Comment: Once again thanks for reply me. My Calling Code On Mat-lab side part from input web cam video processing i got 1-by-8 matrix co-ordinates values  while(1) matrix = [right_lip_x;right_lip_y;left_lip_xy;left_lip_yx;upper_lip_x;upper_lip_y;bottom_lip_x;bottom_lip_y]; %from rest of code available in this same forum   end on Java Code Part Sample Class having private List<List<Integer>> matrix;//Getter Setter                     public List<List<Integer>> getMatrix() {
        return matrix;}

Comment: In that case the first one will work `sample.getMatrix().add(points)` and the sample object must be created only once.

Comment: Thanks for reply me . please let me know brief description with example ?